# Почему в 1-м предложении ставится запятая перед 2-м «и», а в другом нет?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, однородные-члены, ссп

Тут 2 предложения. Но почему в 1-м есть запятая, а во 2-м нет?
Мы видим, что 1-е «и» без запятых, т. к. тесно связаны однородные.

> Было тихо и темно, и сладко пахло травами.

> Он хорошо сложен и крепок и красив старинной русской красотой.

Answer (score 1):

Не буду ничего выдумывать, просто приведу отрывки из правил, в которых эти предложения используются в качестве примеров.

ПАС под редакцией Лопатина ([§ 26. Знаки препинания при однородных членах предложения с союзами и без союзов](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=74#pg74)):

1. > Примечание. Не следует путать повторяющийся союз *и* и союзы *и*, поставленные на разном основании: *Было тихо и темно, и сладко пахло травами* (первое *и* стоит между однородными частями главного члена предложения, а второе *и* присоединяет часть сложного предложения).

Справочник Розенталя ([§ 87. Однородные члены, соединенные повторяющимися союзами](http://rozental.gramatik.ru/xxii-znaki-prepinaniya-v-predlozheniyah-s-odnorodnymi-chlenami/ss-87-odnorodnye-chleny-soedinennye-povtoryayushchimisya-soyuzami)):

2. > **Примечание.** Не ставится запятая, если два однородных члена с союзом и между ними образуют тесно связанную по смыслу группу, соединенную союзом и с третьим однородным членом, например: *Вода давно сбыла в Тереке и быстро **сбегала и сохла** по канавам* (Л. Толстой) (сбегала и сохла образуют парную группу, имеющую общий второстепенный член по канавам); *Чувствовалось, что он хорошо сложен **и крепок и красив***  [*sic*]  *старинной русской красотой* (Фадеев) (парную группу образуют первые два сказуемых)...

Теперь мое примечание. Вполне возможно, что разъяснения не совсем понятны, потому что в тексте правил в предложении вместо тесно связанных "сложен и крепок" **ошибочно** выделены жирным курсивом ***и крепок и красив*** (логика: невозможно быть крепким "старинной русской красотой" — можно быть только красивым).

Answer (score 0):

Потому что в первом случае сложное предложение, а во втором — простое.

Comment: Мне кажется, что автору вопроса не очень понятно объяснение, поэтому вы не могли бы дополнить ответ?  Желательно указать грамматическую основу и роль двух союзов И для обоих предложений. Кроме того, во втором предложении однородные сказуемые делятся на две группы (на какие?), поэтому там нет повторяющегося союза И…И.

Comment: @Sharon так напишите свой ответ)

Comment: Я уже устала писать, мне хочется, чтобы вы дополнили свой ответ, пжста.

Comment: @Sharon моя не хотеть. Моя русский язык плоха знай, ответило как смогло.

Comment: Зато смешить меня вы мастер!  Так и знала, что скажете "не хочу". Тогда прокомментируйте что-нибудь. Скорее всего, наше общество перестало вас устраивать. Неинтересно!  P..S. Странно, что русское слово интерес (от ср.-лат. interesse «иметь важное значение») — обозначено впервые  только у Петра I (1703 г.).

Comment: @Sharon да ничего не перестало. Просто настроения нет. Как говорится, дал Бог серотонин, даст и cелективные ингибиторы обратного захвата. Вот, жду, когда сподобит.

Comment: Где вы только таких слов набираетесь, приходится в словаре искать.  Ну ладно, тогда мы тоже подождем. Эти писатели такие нервные и эмоциональные люди! Но, видно, равнодушно относиться к жизни им просто нельзя.

Comment: @Sharon к сожалению, дело не в писательстве, а в банальном физиологическом нарушении.

Comment: Тогда я желаю вам много-много здоровья....